# Cannot deploy HelloWorld App to Appspot

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been following this Udacity tutorial on how to deploy to Appspot from Eclipse EE.

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud859/lessons/1215898636/concepts/14551185740923#

here are the instructions written out...

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EO3pQ53DQP3SW4LCnOLiUtgAKCWbqXVprBWj0TOlRUM/pub

I believe I have followed it to the letter, but when I try to update the application it insists that the project does not exist and gives me a 404 error. However, if I go to Google Cloud Platform the project is there and I can see the project id.

I have,

1. Changed the application in appengine-web.xml to be the project id hello-around-the-world-155900
2. Upon prompt Granted App Engine appcfg permissions
3. Installed Google eclipse plugin and logged into Google with the same account that is the owner of the project
4. I am using jdk 1.7.0_80 and maven 3.3.9
5. Created a new App engine project and restarted my computer

Here is my appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>hello-around-the-world-155900</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
       <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Here is the console log,

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) > package @ helloworld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - get endpoints discovery doc...
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-discovery-doc, -cp, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/classes;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.4\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.4\appengine-endpoints-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar, -o, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -f, rest, com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints]
Jan 16, 2017 4:15:02 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API Discovery Document written to C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/helloworldendpoints-v1-rest.discovery
[INFO] Using Class Name:com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints
[INFO] Executing endpoints Command=[get-discovery-doc, -cp, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/classes;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.4\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.4\appengine-endpoints-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Joes1\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar, -o, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF, -w, C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints, -f, rpc, com.google.training.helloworld.HelloWorldEndpoints]
Jan 16, 2017 4:15:03 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
API Discovery Document written to C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\generated-sources\appengine-endpoints\WEB-INF/helloworldendpoints-v1-rpc.discovery
[INFO] Endpoints discovery doc generation done.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints] to [C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [51 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Joes1\Downloads\ud859-master\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) < package @ helloworld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.4:update (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Updating Application
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] Updating Google App Engine Application
Jan 16, 2017 4:15:05 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Reading application configuration data...
Jan 16, 2017 4:15:05 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/Joes1/Downloads/ud859-master/Lesson_2/000_Hello_Endpoints/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jan 16, 2017 4:15:05 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users/Joes1/Downloads/ud859-master/Lesson_2/000_Hello_Endpoints/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF/web.xml


Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\Joes1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2557241349360287827.tmp'
5% Scanning for jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=845830179642&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'845830179642'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=845830179642&version=1&
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (project_id=u'845830179642'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.

Please see the logs [C:\Users\Joes1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4148446068266547082.log] for further information.
```

Could someone please give advice on what I am missing? There doesn't seem to be many variables here and many people use this service so there must be an answer somewhere.

Comment: close the </appengine-web-app> tag and try again. and intend the </system-properties> tag too.

Comment: Sorry, didn't indent it properly in the stack overflow editor. Should appear like it was supposed to now.

Comment: Seems everything alright with your appengine-web.xml file. My guess is maybe you are using different account credential to upload the project. Even thought you mention that you did the appcfg permission. Please make sure your using the correct account.

Comment: Huh, this is bizarre, throughout the entire process I have only used one google account.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

`This application does not exist (project_id=u'845830179642'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.`

The problem here is that you need to create an `App Engine application` in the GCP project to be able to deploy. You can do that with the `gcloud app create` command in the command line (`beta` is not necessary anymore), or you can go to the App Engine Dashboard in Cloud Console and create it.

See the documentation about how to create a GCP project and the App Engine application:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/console/